# Scrape Amazon deals page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to get ASINs from hrefs links in an amazon page.
ASINs are unique blocks of 10 letters and/or numbers that identify items.

Particularly I tried to scrape https://www.amazon.it/gp/goldbox/ with scrapy (python). 
In this page there are a lot of links that contains ASINs.

```
 <a id="dealImage" class="a-link-normal" href="https://www.amazon.it/Marantz-TT5005-Giradischi-Equalizzatore-Incorporato/dp/B008NIV668/ref=gbph_img_s-3_c128_ca594162?smid=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_p=8accddad-a52b-4a55-a9e1-760ad483c128&amp;pf_rd_s=slot-3&amp;pf_rd_t=701&amp;pf_rd_i=gb_main&amp;pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_r=5E0HASYCKDNV4YWQCJSJ">
        ...
```

every link contain the asin next to "../db/ASIN.."

This is my code, but I can't scrape and get ASINs...

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = "amazon"

      def start_requests(self):
          urls = [
         'https://www.amazon.it/gp/goldbox/'
          ]
          for url in urls:
              yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


      def parse(self, response):
          page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "a-link-normal")]')
```

I can split the link with this: split("/dp/")

hope someone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Risparmia su Bic Cristal Original - ")]').re(r'"reviewAsin" : "([^"]+)"')
```

There are different type of asins, can not decide which to parse.
You can write your pattern and grab them.

checkout this
    response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Risparmia su Bic Cristal Original - ")]').extract()

Answer (score 0):

The html there is generated by javascript, which is based on json objects. You can pull data directly from these json objects.
You may get all asins by this expression:

/reviewAsin\" : \"([A-Z0-9]+)\"/